# Is there a way to respond to a change of System colors at design time?

Tags: c#, user-controls, systemcolors

I've got a usercontrol (derived from ContainerControl) which I'm filling using a gradient. The first gradient color may or may not be a system color, like `SystemColors.Highlight`.
The second gradient color is derived from the first one, by means of `ControlPaint.Light(firstColor)` or something similar.

I can easily handle changing system colors at runtime by overriding `OnSystemColorsChanged`, and it works without any trouble. But if the control is placed on a form at design time, and then the system colors are changed, the second color stays the same, probably due to `OnSystemColorsChanged` not being called at design time.

I can reset the second color manually since I provide ShouldSerialize- and Reset- methods for the second color property, and therefore the default value for that property changes accordingly when the system color changes.

So, is there any way to catch a system color change at design time?

**Edit:**

Here's a minimized code sample:

```
public class Test : ContainerControl
{

public Test()
{
  ResetColor1();
  ResetColor2();
}

private bool _resetColor2;


// Color 1 stuff
private Color _color1 = Color.Empty;
public System.Drawing.Color Color1
{
  get { return _color1; }
  set
  {
    _resetColor2 = !ShouldSerializeColor2();
    _color1 = value;
    if (_resetColor2)
      ResetColor2();
    Invalidate();
  }
}
// Defaults Color 1
private Color DefaultColor1 { get { return SystemColors.Highlight; } }
public bool ShouldSerializeColor1()
{
  return !Color1.Equals(Color.Empty) && !Color1.Equals(DefaultColor1);
}
public void ResetColor1()
{
  Color1 = DefaultColor1;
}

// Color 2 stuff
private Color _color2 = Color.Empty;
public System.Drawing.Color Color2
{
  get { return _color2; }
  set
  {
    _color2 = value;
    Invalidate();
  }
}
private Color DefaultColor2 { get { return ControlPaint.Light(Color1); } }
public bool ShouldSerializeColor2()
{
  return !Color2.Equals(DefaultColor2);
}
public void ResetColor2()
{
  Color2 = DefaultColor2;
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnPaint(e);
  using (LinearGradientBrush b = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, Color1, Color2, LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal))
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, this.ClientRectangle);
}

protected override void OnSystemColorsChanged(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnSystemColorsChanged(e);

  if (_resetColor2)
    ResetColor2();
}
}
```

If you put this control onto a form, this code will do the following:

- Default Color1 to SystemColors.Highlight
- Default Color2 to a lighter color
- If Color2 is not changed manually, it will automatically derive from Color1
- If system colors change at runtime, Color1 and Color2 will both change
- If system colors change at design time, only Color1 will change

Comment: Can we see some code? I think I have the reason y possibly the solution, but I want to be sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be too surprised if the event is suppressed in design mode, SystemEvents are tricky because they are static events.  Solve your problem by setting a bool flag in the property setter for Color2 to indicate that it matches the default color.  Always use ControlPaint.Light() when the flag is set.

Comment: You were right there, `SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` is suppressed. `SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged` seems to work, but your approach seems easier to handle. I'll check both approaches and then pick the easier one.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the [SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged.aspx) event, I believe.

Comment: Close, thanks for the pointer. It looks as if `SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged` works in Design mode. I need to test this extensively now ...